# How to override the default TailWind preflight setup for img and svg tags?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

Based on the official TailWind [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#images-are-block-level), `img` and `svg` (and some other) elements use `display: block`. Is there a way to override this default behavior so that I change it to `display: inline`?

My project is quite new, so `tailwind.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "search-icon": "url('images/search_black.svg')",
      },
      colors: {
        "ef-purple-100": "#ebdbf8", // ...
      },
      borderWidth: {
        6: "6px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: What stops you to simply add your own css file and write `body img { display:inline; }`? (Note: `body img` elevates the rule’s specificity and ensure overriding rule of tailwind)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set in a `.css` file :

```
img, svg {
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
<style module>
img, svg {
   display: inline;
}
</style>

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "search-icon": "url('images/search_black.svg')",
      },
      colors: {
        "ef-purple-100": "#ebdbf8", // ...
      },
      borderWidth: {
        6: "6px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```